# flutter sms package read sms as read

Tags: flutter

I was working on an sms application in flutter. For that I'm using **flutter_sms** packages by **babariviere**. I want to mark a thread as read. Can any one tell How to achieve that.I have read the documentaion but didnt find.Maybe someone here could help me. Thank-You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot with the current implementation of https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_sms . This package can only `android.permission.SEND_SMS`, not `android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS`, `android.permission.READ_SMS` nor `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS`. You can create a github issue asking for your feature request https://github.com/AppleEducate/plugins/issues.